# Usar BackGroundWorker mientras se lee archivo excel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

Tengo una función para cargar un Excel, leerlo y luego guardar la información en mi base de datos, mientras leo y guardo la información, mi interfaz se queda congelada. Quiero mostrar a mi usuario a través de una barra de progreso el porcentaje que lleva el proceso. Sé que debo usar BackGroundWorker pero no entiendo cómo implementarlo en mi función además de que quiero que todo se ejecute al presionar mi boton.
Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano.

esta es mi funcion:

```
private void Btn_Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        DataSet validarnumorder;
        dayNum = dayNumber;

        saveFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        saveFile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        saveFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx";
        saveFile.Title = "Open an image";
        saveFile.AddExtension = true;
        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
  //Barprogress
        load.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        fileName = saveFile.FileName;
            Console.WriteLine(saveFile.SafeFileName);
            Console.WriteLine(saveFile.FileName);
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;
            Doc = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
            ooSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Doc.ActiveSheet;

        if (saveFile.FileName.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se encontro archivo");
            }
            else
            {
                //La busqueda de valores en el archivo de excel que se encuentre abierto empieza en la fila 2, por eso a la variable s se le está asignando el valor de 2.
                s = 2;

                        do
                        {


                //La variable validarorderNum valida si el número de orden existe en la base de datos, por lo que en caso de que ya exista el número de orden, se lance un mensaje que le indique a la persona que el número de orden ya existe en la aplicación por lo que no puede volverlo a ingresar ya que los número de orden no pueden estar repetidos en el programa.

                validarnumorder = conexion.fillTable("select Field1 from [mytable] where Field1 ='" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "' ");
                if (validarnumorder.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count == 0)
                       {
                    //Se inicializa un insert en la base de datos en dado caso de que el número de orden no exista en la base de datos y le asigna los valores cargados en el excel con el plan de producción.
                conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable] ([first] ,[first] ,[first] ,[first],[Users] ,[first], [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + s + "").Value + "','" + dayNum + "', 0, 0, 0, '" + dayNum + "') ");

               conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable2] ([first] ,[first],[first],[first],[first] ,[first],[first], [first],  [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + null + "','" + "NORMAL" + "', '" + null + "', '" + "Nothing" + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" + s + "").Value + "') ");


                            }
                            else
                            {
      MessageBox.Show("En el plan cargado se encuentra un número de orden ya existente, el número de orden es: '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "'");
                            }
                            s++;
   } while (oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value != null);
            load.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    MessageBox.Show("Información guardada con exito");
     saveFile.FileName = null;
            }
            Doc.Close();
            ooSheet = null;
            Doc = null;
            oXL = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontro el archivo");
        }



        ListView();       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagino que quieres usar BackgroundWorker porque así se requiere, pero si lo haces por cuenta propia te comento que hay alternativas más "rápidas" de implementar...

Si quieres usar BackgroundWorker, adapté un código a tu ejemplo, sería más o menos así:

```
private void Btn_Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    saveFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    saveFile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
    saveFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx";
    saveFile.Title = "Open an image";
    saveFile.AddExtension = true;
    if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        IniciarProcesoDeCarga(saveFile.FileName);
    }
}

private BackgroundWorker _loadingWorker;
public BackgroundWorker LoadingWorker
{
    get { return _loadingWorker; }
    set { _loadingWorker = value; }
}

private void IniciarProcesoDeCarga(string ruta)
{
    if (File.Exists(ruta))
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                bt_seleccionar.IsEnabled = false;       //para que no puedad pulsar el botón 2 veces seguidas  
            }));

            LoadingWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            LoadingWorker.DoWork += LoadingWorker_DoWork;
            LoadingWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            LoadingWorker.ProgressChanged += LoadingWorker_ProgressChanged;
            LoadingWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += LoadingWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            LoadingWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}
private bool SuccesfullyLoaded = false;

void LoadingWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Barprogress
        //Usas Dispatcher para cuando necesites hacer algo en la interfaz de usuario ya que dentro de un BackgroundWorker estás en "otro hilo"
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            {  
                load.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                fileName = saveFile.FileName;
                Console.WriteLine(saveFile.SafeFileName);
                Console.WriteLine(saveFile.FileName);
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;
                Doc = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                ooSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Doc.ActiveSheet;
            }));
            //La busqueda de valores en el archivo de excel que se encuentre abierto empieza en la fila 2, por eso a la variable s se le está asignando el valor de 2.
            s = 2;

            do
            { 
                //La variable validarorderNum valida si el número de orden existe en la base de datos, por lo que en caso de que ya exista el número de orden, se lance un mensaje que le indique a la persona que el número de orden ya existe en la aplicación por lo que no puede volverlo a ingresar ya que los número de orden no pueden estar repetidos en el programa.

                validarnumorder = conexion.fillTable("select Field1 from [mytable] where Field1 ='" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "' ");
                if (validarnumorder.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    //Se inicializa un insert en la base de datos en dado caso de que el número de orden no exista en la base de datos y le asigna los valores cargados en el excel con el plan de producción.
                    conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable] ([first] ,[first] ,[first] ,[first],[Users] ,[first], [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + s + "").Value + "','" + dayNum + "', 0, 0, 0, '" + dayNum + "') ");

                    //avisa que el proceso está al 50%
                    LoadingWorker.ReportProgress(50);

                    conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable2] ([first] ,[first],[first],[first],[first] ,[first],[first], [first],  [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + null + "','" + "NORMAL" + "', '" + null + "', '" + "Nothing" + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" + s + "").Value + "') ");

                    //avisa que el proceso está al 100%
                    LoadingWorker.ReportProgress(100);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("En el plan cargado se encuentra un número de orden ya existente, el número de orden es: '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "'");
                }
                s++;
            } 

            while (oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value != null);
            load.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            MessageBox.Show("Información guardada con exito");
            SuccesfullyLoaded = true;
            saveFile.FileName = null;

            Doc.Close();
            ooSheet = null;
            Doc = null;
            oXL = null;

    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SuccesfullyLoaded = false;
        //CONTROL DE EX
        MessageBox.Show("BLABLA");
    }
}

//Si quieres controlar el porcentaje de carga a través de un stream y un buffer podrías usar esta función
//ver la función que sigue que muestra como funciona.
//para este ejemplo no aplica, solo una idea.
public double BytesToKb(long bytes)
{
    return Math.Truncate(bytes / 1024f);
}

/*
    * Cuando DoWork está funcionando puedes indicarle que te avise el porcentaje de avance, acá se controla eso.
*/

//LoadingValue es un INT que lo aplicas, por ejemplo, a una ProgressBar 
//LoadingMessage un mensaje que indica el avance 
//Puedes cambiarlo y colocar sus valores directo en una ProgressBar.Value o un TextBox.Text
void LoadingWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //si usaras el método anterior acá lo aplicarías así:
    int cargado = e.ProgressPercentage;  //0
    int total = (int)BytesToKb(FileInformation.Length);
    var progress = Math.Round(cargado * 100.0 / total);
    var progresstext = Math.Round(cargado * 100.0 / total, 2);

    //sino solo usa esto
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
        { 
            LoadingValue = progress; 
            LoadingMessage = (cargado + "kb de " + BytesToKb(FileInformation.Length) + "kb (" + progresstext + "%)");
        }));

}

/*
    * Esto se gatilla automáticamente al terminar lo que se programó
*/
void LoadingWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SuccesfullyLoaded)
    {
        //se cargó todo bien... acá deberías mandar un mensaje diciendo que está OK.
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                bt_seleccionar.IsEnabled = false; //desbloquea el boton de seleccionar
            }));
    }
    else
    {
        //falló la carga
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { LoadingValue = 0; }));
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { LoadingMessage = "Carga fallida"; }));
    if (MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar el archivo.\nDetalle: " + error_msge + "\n\n¿Desea enviar la tarea de todas formas?\n\nPulse NO o Cancelar par volver a intentarlo", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
    CurrentTarea.FileName = null;
    CurrentTarea.FtpFileName = null;
    ContinueSaving(false);
    }
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, como te comenté, hay alternativas, BW es útil porque puedes controlar el porcentaje de avance, pero eso lo prefiero para movimiento de datos grandes, que realmente puedan tardar, en caso contrario con TASK se hace más rápido..

Acá un ejemplo con TASK

```
private void Btn_Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tsk = CargarAsync();
}

async Task CargarAsync()
{
    try
    {
        bool res = await Task.Run(() => CargarAhora());
        //
        if(res)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Listo");
        }
        else
        {
            //MENSAJE O ACCIÓN SI FALLA
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error leyendo los datos desde archivo: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

//Si te indica algún error relacionado al hilo de ejecución aplicar Dispstcher como en el ejemplo anterior
public bool CargarAhora()
{
    DataSet validarnumorder;
    dayNum = dayNumber;

    saveFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    saveFile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
    saveFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx";
    saveFile.Title = "Open an image";
    saveFile.AddExtension = true;
    try 
    {
        if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            //Barprogress
            load.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            fileName = saveFile.FileName;
            Console.WriteLine(saveFile.SafeFileName);
            Console.WriteLine(saveFile.FileName);
            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;
            Doc = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
            ooSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Doc.ActiveSheet;

            if (saveFile.FileName.Equals(""))
            {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontro archivo");
            }
            else
            {
            //La busqueda de valores en el archivo de excel que se encuentre abierto empieza en la fila 2, por eso a la variable s se le está asignando el valor de 2.
            s = 2;

            do
            { 
                //La variable validarorderNum valida si el número de orden existe en la base de datos, por lo que en caso de que ya exista el número de orden, se lance un mensaje que le indique a la persona que el número de orden ya existe en la aplicación por lo que no puede volverlo a ingresar ya que los número de orden no pueden estar repetidos en el programa.

                validarnumorder = conexion.fillTable("select Field1 from [mytable] where Field1 ='" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "' ");
                if (validarnumorder.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    //Se inicializa un insert en la base de datos en dado caso de que el número de orden no exista en la base de datos y le asigna los valores cargados en el excel con el plan de producción.
                    conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable] ([first] ,[first] ,[first] ,[first],[Users] ,[first], [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + s + "").Value + "','" + dayNum + "', 0, 0, 0, '" + dayNum + "') ");

                    conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable2] ([first] ,[first],[first],[first],[first] ,[first],[first], [first],  [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + null + "','" + "NORMAL" + "', '" + null + "', '" + "Nothing" + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" + s + "").Value + "') ");


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("En el plan cargado se encuentra un número de orden ya existente, el número de orden es: '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "'");
                }
                s++;
            } while (oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value != null);
            load.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            MessageBox.Show("Información guardada con exito");
            saveFile.FileName = null;
        }
        Doc.Close();
        ooSheet = null;
        Doc = null;
        oXL = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontro el archivo");
        }
        ListView();     
        return true;    
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Si quieres algo más detallado da más info de tu pregunta.
Un saludo.

EDIT:

Agrego:

```
private FileInfo _fileInformation;
public FileInfo FileInformation
{
    get { return _fileInformation; }
    set
    {
        _fileInformation = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FileInformation");
    }
}

private double _loadingValue = 0;
public double LoadingValue
{
    get { return _loadingValue; }
    set
    { 
        _loadingValue = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingValue");            
    }
}

private string _loadingMessage = string.Empty;
public string LoadingMessage
{
    get { return _loadingMessage; }
    set 
    {
        _loadingMessage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingMessage");
    }
}
```

Como te indico en el código más arriba, las 2 ultimas variables las puedes omitir y colocar sus valores directo en un ProgressBar y un TextBlock.

Quedo atento.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta estoy probando ambas opciones y la segunda opcion es buena, pero me el requerimiento es la barra de progreso (La primera opcion), al implementar no reconoce FileInformation, LoadingValue y LoadingMessage. De donde salen esas variables?

Comment: Agrego lo que preguntas a la respuesta, pero así rápido, FileInformation es para obtener info del archivo más facil, y las otras 2 son solo variables locales para hacer más amigable el proceso.. Lo que ocurre es que, por ejemplo, usando MVVM puedes Bindear un TextBox o TextBlock a LoadingMessage y así tener info de lo que está haciendo tu código mientras "lo hace".

Comment: En todo caso si tu código solo hace 2 cosas, leer el archivo y subir los datos, puedes usar la 2da opción y setear el valor de la ProgressBar "manualmente". Antes del "await" el código no ha leido nada, después del await ya hizo todo el trabajo, podrias ponerlo como 50% antes del await y 100 despues...

Comment: muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, me surgio otra duda y en que momento se llama el metodo RaisePropertyChanged ?

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged se debe colocar en el SET de todas las "Properties" (variables de clase) que estén siendo "Bindeadas" por algún control de la interfaz de usuario, ocurre que tu puedes tener un String conectado a un TextBox, pero podrías cambiar su valor mil veces y el TextBox seguiría igual, para eso se usa INotifyPropertyChanged que permite comunicar esos cambios a la interfaz, pero primero debe "implementarse" y en este caso yo te puse mi implementación que es RaisePropertyChanged. En resumen, agrega RaisePropertyChanged("NombreDeLaVariable") en todas las variables y listo :)

Comment: no logro comprender esta parte, pues marca error y dice que RaisePropertyChanged no existe en el contexto actual. Lo declaraste asi RaisePropertyChanged("FileInformation"); y por lo que entiendo el string que se encuentra dentro es el nombre de algun elemento visual de mi proyecto?

Comment: El String que pones dentro de RaisePropertyChanged es la misma Property donde está alojada la llamada a RaisePropertyChanged tal cual, fíjate que FileInformation (con la inicial en mayúscula) es una referencia a _fileInformation (con guion bajo). Esa referencia es la que va dentro de RaisePropertyChanged y RaisePropertyChanged debes implementarlo en todos tus ViewModels (o en una Interface para centralizarlo) y también en los Models. FINALMENTE debes agregar using System.ComponentModel; para que funcione.